# UITableViewCell issue in iOS 7 with image background

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm having an issue in iOS7 with `UITableViewCell` when I set its background to a pattern i.e. :

```
tableViewCell.backgroundView = 
     [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.cellBackgroundImage];
```

When I do this, and I have the table view cell separator turned off, I still get this:

[image: Bug example]

A white line is appearing every other row. Even when I don't have the separator turned off, I still get this extra line on top of the normal separator. This is not happening < iOS7. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: @sangony - Yeah doesn't work, the issue seems to be separate from the separator, cause even when I have a separator it will put that extra white space.

Comment: Post your tableView delegate and cell creation code or an example project.

Comment: From your pic it looks like you have a white line between images 1 and 2 but not between 2 and 3. Have you double checked that your images are all the same height?

Comment: @sangony - Yeah it's not the images, I actually found a solution see my response to Michael G. Emmons answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
   self.tableView.rowHeight = self.cellBackgroundImage.size.height;
}
```

If you are still having issues, likely there is a bounds problem in your tableView somewhere. You can try clipping to bounds and see if there is still the same issue:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = 
          [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Is our layout bleeding into other cells? Let's see.
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

    cell.backgroundView = 
          [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.cellBackgroundImage];
    // rest of code ...

    return cell;
}
```

If your issue goes away after clipping, you need to figure out where in your layout you are bleeding over into other cells.

Comment: I actually found a solution, it's: I fixed the problem by replacing the above line of code with:

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.cellBackgroundImage];

Comment: Think you could post that as your answer for me and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by replacing the above line of code with:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.cellBackgroundImage];
```